# WordPress multisite installation subdomains not working properly

Tags: multisite, urls, domain

I have a WordPress multisite installation example.com, with subdomains example.com/foo, and example.com/bar.

I'm trying to change the site name of example.com/foo to foo.example.com.

Normally I just change this in Network Admin > Sites, and then change a particular site's name in the "Site Address (URL)" field - e.g. to foo.example.com

Having done this, foo.example.com now points to the right homepage... But all subsequent pages are "Not found". E.g. example.com/foo/news-story had content, but foo.example.com/news-story is "Not found".

What have I missed?

Comment: Is the multisite installation set up for subdomains or subdirectories? Your post specifies both - but you must select one or the other during the original network setup. If you're attempting to transition from subdirectories to subdomains, have you followed the steps in ["Switching Network Types"](https://wordpress.org/support/article/multisite-network-administration/#switching-network-types)?

Answer (score 0):

Switching from sub directories to sub domains is not easy. Start by looking at https://wordpress.org/support/article/multisite-network-administration/#switching-network-types, besides that, you might also need to run search + replace queries on the database to update the URLs on the content, and re-save the permalink structure.